# Docker Composer File Configuration

Tags: docker, docker-compose

```
version: "1.0"
services:
    es:
        image: "elasticsearch:7.6.1"
        container_name: myelasticsearch
        ports:
            - "9200:9200"
            - "9300:9300"
        environment:
            - discovery.type=single-node
    re:
        image: redis
        container_name: myredis
        ports:
            - "6379:6379"
    rab:
        image: "rabbitmq:3-management"  
        container_name: myrabbitmq
        ports:
            - "15672:15672"
            - "5672:5672"
```

when i run docker-composer up it shows ERROR: Version "1.0" in ".\docker-compose.yml" is invalid. I am not finding why this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
version: "3.7"
services:
    es:
        image: "elasticsearch:7.6.1"
        container_name: myelasticsearch
        ports:
            - "9200:9200"
            - "9300:9300"
        environment:
            - discovery.type=single-node
    re:
        image: redis
        container_name: myredis
        ports:
            - "6379:6379"
    rabbitmq:
        image: "rabbitmq:3-management"  
        container_name: myrabbitmq
        ports:
            - "15672:15672"
            - "5672:5672"
```

Answer (score 3):

There are three major versions of the [`docker-compose.yml` file itself](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/).  You typically want the latest one

```yaml
version: '3.7'
```

[Version 1](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v1/) was significant different from its successors: it put all of the service definitions at the top level, and didn't support top-level `version:` or `services:` keys.  There are a number of other changes as well; if you need custom network configuration, Swarm support, or to specify the image name of a locally-built image, version 1 doesn't have any of these things.